# MonoTouch build fails

Tags: ios-simulator, xamarin.ios

Okay, I have been building using MonoTouch for about 6 hours and I have hit a wall, what ever I do to try and run and build my application I get build failed, but the build window is not tell me why it is failing.

The code is very basic and is correct.

Could anyone help me out here please?

```
Building: HelloiPhone (Debug|iPhoneSimulator)

Building Solution HelloiPhone

Building: HelloiPhone (Debug|iPhoneSimulator)
Performing main compilation...

Updating CodeBehind files

Compiling interface definitions
ibtool "/Users/Bryan/Projects/HelloiPhone/HelloiPhone/MainWindow.xib" --compile "/Users/Bryan/Projects/HelloiPhone/HelloiPhone/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/HelloiPhone.app/MainWindow.nib"

Build failed. ApplicationName='ibtool', CommandLine='"/Users/Bryan/Projects/HelloiPhone/HelloiPhone/MainWindow.xib" --compile "/Users/Bryan/Projects/HelloiPhone/HelloiPhone/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/HelloiPhone.app/MainWindow.nib"', CurrentDirectory='/Users/Bryan/Projects/HelloiPhone/HelloiPhone/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug'
```

Comment: Have you, by any chance, upgraded to Snow Leopard since installing the Apple iPhone SDK?

Comment: I have a brand new MacBook Air OS X 10.6.2, not sure if it is Snow Leopard, how do I tell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the iPhone SDK for OSX 10.5 installed, I needed to go download and
install the correct iPhone SDK for OSX 10.6 since you are running 10.6.2.

Now fully working

Answer (score 0):

Do you have XCode and the iPhone SDK installed? You can't develop using MT without it.

Comment: Yes, both installed and working.

I can create Objective C iPhone apps without any problems